# Locust stalled after temporarily getting Error 500

Tags: python, locust

When the loadbalancer in front of the tested https web site fails-over, this generates some HTTPError 500 for few seconds, then Locust hangs:

- The response time graph stops (empty graph)
- The total requests per second turns to a wrong green flat line.
  If I just stop & start the test, locust restart monitoring properly the response time.
- We can see some HTTPError 500 in the Failures tab

Is this a bug ?
How can I make sure Locust kills and restarts users, either manually or when timeout ?

My attempt to regularly "RescheduleTaskImmediately" did not help.

My locustfile.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import random
from locust import HttpUser, task, between, TaskSet
from locust.exception import InterruptTaskSet, RescheduleTaskImmediately

URL_LIST = [
"/url1",
"/url2",
"/url3",
]

class QuickstartTask(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(0.1, 0.5)
    connection_timeout = 15.0
    network_timeout = 20.0

    def on_start(self):
        # Required to use the http_proxy & https_proxy
        self.client.trust_env = True
        print("New user started")
        self.client.timeout = 5
        self.client.get("/")
        self.client.get("/favicon.ico")
        self.getcount = 0

    def on_stop(self):
        print("User stopped")

    @task
    def track_and_trace(self):
        url = URL_LIST[random.randrange(0,len(URL_LIST))]
        self.client.get(url, name=url[:50])
        self.getcount += 1
        if self.getcount > 50 and (random.randrange(0,1000) > 990 or self.getcount > 200):
            print(f'Reschedule after {self.getcount} requests.')
            self.client.cookies.clear()
            self.getcount = 0
            raise RescheduleTaskImmediately
```

Comment: I've seen this behavior if you have multiple people attempting to access the Locust UI simultaneously. Are you the only one trying to view the UI or are there others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each locust runs in a thread. If the thread gets blocked, it doesn't take further actions.

```
self.client.get(url, name=url[:50], timeout=.1)
```

Something like this is probably what you need, potentially with a try/except to do something different when you get an http timeout exception.

Comment: Tks, will retry a fail-over. Just had to provide a higher timeout of 3s since .1 was way too short. 
Also, I did update the case since I noticed 16 Error 500 from the load balancer during fail-over. (running with 20 users). But even if 4 users did not get any error 500, the RT graph stops, and other lines remains horizontal.

Comment: I'll investigate more, since this option to set the timeout in the get instead than at the user level seems to really make a difference. So far, no problem with a short timeout like that set to 3.0s. It seems like you did find a workaround !

Comment: There's probably a second bug in your setup on the app side, where its failing to respond in a timely matter. Something like harikiri for uwsgi to that if the app stops responding, users get an error message instead of an indefinite hang.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the problem you're describing with the charts on the Locust UI has nothing to do with the errors your Locust users are hitting. I've seen this behavior if you have multiple people attempting to access the Locust UI simultaneously. Locust uses Flask to create and serve the UI. Flask by itself (at the way Locust is using it) doesn't do well with multiple connections.

If Person A starts using Locust UI and starts a test, they'll see stats and everything working fine until Person B loads the Locust UI. Person B will then see things working fine but Person A will experience issues as you describe, with the test seemingly stalling and charts not updating properly. In that state, sometimes starting a new test would resolve it temporarily, other times you need to refresh. Either way, A and B would be fighting between each other for a working UI.

The solution in this case would be to put Locust behind a reverse proxy using something such as Nginx. Nginx then maintains a single connection to Locust and all users connect through Nginx. Locust's UI should then continue to work for all connected users with correctly updating stats and charts.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the answer but in my case this is well a locust problem :
- I'm using locust for some months, and can see this vehaviour every single time, at the exact time the load balancer fail-over or if the servers stops responding.
- I also faced the problem you describe, but then the entire GUI is unavailable. Here I'm alone on it, and the graph continues to progress, just steady horizontal lines for the number of requests and users. Only the RT stops from being drawed.